# Remove item from ArrayList doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am trying to remove an object from an ArrayList and here is the code

```
Read re = new Read(connectionString);
List<Student> arcurrentCuourseStudnets= re.currentCourseStudents(); //Reading the students in this course it is return ArrayList with the IDs of all students in this course
List<Student> arstuedents=new List<Student>();
foreach (object ob1 in arcurrentCuourseStudnets)
{
      arstuedents.Add(re.student(((currentCourseStudents)ob1).StudentID.ToString()));//return the student as object indicates its ID FirstName .... 
}

listBoxSS.Items.Clear();
Read search = new Read(connectionString);
List<Student> arr = search.students();//Read all the students in DB


foreach (object ob in arstuedents)
{
    arr.Remove(ob); //remove the Current Course Students from the List to prevent the duplicate's 
}
```

`this arr.Remove()` doesn't work even when I try to do the following  arr[0].Equals(arstuedents[0]); it gives false every time  I look to the values and IDs for the students of  arr[0] and arstuedents[0] I found it the same but it gives false

```
foreach (object o in arr)
{
    listBoxSS.Items.Add((Student)o);
}
```

What is the problem and why does the compiler not see it as equal?

//I did the following things

```
 public class Student : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
     int student_id;
     string first_name;
     string last_name;
     string mother_name;
     string father_name;
     DateTime birth_date;
     string education_level;
     string address;
     string notes;
     int[] phones;
    public Student(string first_name, string last_name, string mother_name, string father_name, DateTime birth_date, string education_level, string address, string notes)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.mother_name = mother_name;
        this.father_name = father_name;
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
        this.education_level = education_level;
        this.address = address;
        this.notes = notes;
    }
    public Student(int student_id, string first_name, string last_name, string mother_name, string father_name, DateTime birth_date, string education_level, string address, string notes)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.mother_name = mother_name;
        this.father_name = father_name;
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
        this.education_level = education_level;
        this.address = address;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.student_id = student_id;
    }
    public int Student_id
    { get { return student_id; } }
    public string First_name
    { 
        get
        { return first_name; }
        set
        { first_name = value; }
    }
    public string Last_name
    { 
        get 
        { return last_name; }
        set
        { last_name = value; }
    }
    public string Mother_name
    { 
        get { return mother_name; }
        set
        { mother_name = value; }
    }
    public string Father_name
    { 
        get { return father_name; }
        set
        { mother_name = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Birth_date
    { 
        get { return birth_date; }
        set
        { birth_date = value; }
    }
    public string Education_level
    { 
        get { return education_level; }
        set
        { education_level = value; }
    }
    public string Address
    { 
        get { return address; }
        set
        { education_level = value; }
    }
    public string Notes
    { 
        get { return notes; }
        set
        { notes = value; }
    }
    public int[] Phones
    {
        get { return phones; }
        set { phones = value; }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (phones != null && phones[0] != 0)
            return first_name.PadRight(30, ' ') + father_name.PadRight(30, ' ') + last_name.PadRight(30, ' ') + phones[0].ToString();
        else
            return first_name.PadRight(30, ' ') + father_name.PadRight(30, ' ') + last_name;
    }

    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        return (x.Student_id == y.Student_id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

//is that what you mean?

Comment: you **probabbly** operate on value types, even if it's difficutl to deduct from this post.

Comment: You can implement your own `EqualityComparer` if you want to make them equal based on the values.

Comment: yes I am thinking of something like this but how to override the Arraylist.Equal

Comment: Two objects are **not** `Equal` just because they contain the same data.

Comment: @yasser it is `Student` that needs to implement `Equals`. You should not override `ArrayList.Equals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `Remove` method will only remove the exact instance being passed in.  It will not remove another instance of the same type that just happens to be populated with the same values.  Therefore, unless `search.students` returns the same instances of the objects as `re.currentCourseStudents`, it will never find a match and remove it.

Either you need to search through `arr` for matches based on some unique property value and then remove it, or you will need to override the Equals method on that type (whatever type the objects are that are in that list).  I say this because according to the MSDN, the `ArrayList.Remove` method uses `Object.Equals` to determin equality:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove.aspx

For instance, if the objects are all `Student` objects, in your `Student` class, you would need to override the `Equals` method, as such:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Student other = obj as Student;
    if (other != null)
        return (obj.Id == this.Id);
    else
        return base.Equals(obj);
}
```

Also, I would feel I have failed you in some way if I didn't mention the fact that the use of `ArrayList` should be discouraged.  If the lists contain only `Student` objects, then you should be using `List<Student>` or some other type-specific collection, if possible.

However, if your `Student` class inherits from a base class that seals the `Equals` method, such as `DependencyObject`, then you will not be able to override the equality check and therefore you must use a different type of list which checks for equality in a different way.  If you choose to use the `List<Student>` type of list, its `Remove` method checks your objects for equality using `IEquatable`:

```
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        return (Student_Id == other.Studend_Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to override the Equals just in this case I have a unique student ID and I can make the search depending on it

Comment: What type are the objects?  Are they all the same type?  Are they a type you have defined, or are they a built-in type from one of the framework libraries?  It all depends.

Comment: they are all the same types that i have been defined

Comment: public Student(int id,string first_name, string last_name, string mother_name, string father_name, DateTime birth_date, string education_level, string address, string notes)

Comment: Error 2 : cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.Equals(object)' because it is sealed  29 30 ISSI2

Comment: @yasser Yes, that's what I meant.  Does that not work when you use a `List<Student>` list?

Comment: Even I tried to debug it but it seems that the debugger don't compile it

Comment: @yasser What error does it give?  I noticed that one of the constructors for `Student` does not take a `student_id`.  My solution assumed that every student would have a unique ID, otherwise it won't be able to tell if they are the same.

Comment: @SteveDog yes one constructor only to insert the data into the DB but the other constructor is to Read the data from the DB in this situation the ID is presented, the problem is that the remove from the list doesn't work there is no error or exception

Comment: @yasser Sorry about that.  Wrong interface.  Try my updated example.

Comment: @SteveDog Dude I love you, WOOOOW That's Awesome and Cool Thank you very very much, finally it's work